# object Object asignado a una variable

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Es posible recuperar la propiedad de un objeto la cual es otro objeto que fue asignado a una variable ? (a un string en este caso 'valor')

Por ejemplo :

```
let foo = { propiedad : 1 }
let objeto = {};

objeto[foo] = 'valor'

console.log(objeto) 

/* 

Imprime
{ '[object Object]': 'valor' }

*/
```

Por ejemplo que el console.log imprima **{ { propiedad : 1 } : 'valor'}** o algo así ?

PD : Intenté recuperando el Object.keys / JSON.stringify o similar, pero sigue imprimiendo el **object Object** como string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El **objeto** `foo` lo estás usando como **clave** de `objeto` **directamente**, y por eso obtienes el siguiente resultado:

```js
let foo = { propiedad : 1 }
let objeto = {};

objeto[foo] = 'valor';

console.log(objeto)
```

Deberías convertir el objeto a cadena de texto con [**`JSON.stringify()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) de esta forma:

```js
let foo = { propiedad : 1 }
let objeto = {};

objeto[JSON.stringify(foo)] = 'valor';

console.log(JSON.stringify(foo)); // obtengo {"propiedad":1}
console.log(objeto);
```

Comment: bacán, gracias,  quedaría la clave como string entonces

Comment: @Kanoi exactamente, eso es lo que ocurre, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

De manera corta: no, todos las object keys deben de ser un string, al asignarlo le hace un Stringify, y el verdadero key de tu objeto es "object Object".
Si quieres usar un object como key puedes usar un [Map](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_maps.asp)

```js
let foo = { propiedad : 1 };

let myMap = new Map();

myMap.set(foo, 'valor')

console.log(myMap.get(foo))
```